# Adjust Bar Graph Location In Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Thanks for your time:

I have a Flask app that creates a bar graph.

This function:

```
def make_bar(g_title, y_title, x_labels, data_series, file_name, cat_title,
             x_title):
    rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 6.55, 3.8
    n_groups = 13
    bar_width = 0.35
    opacity = 0.4
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    index = np.arange(n_groups)
    error_config = {'ecolor': '0.3'}
    plt.bar(index, tuple(data_series[0][1]), bar_width,
                     alpha=opacity,
                     color='b',
                     error_kw=error_config,
                     label='{}'.format(data_series[0][0]))
    plt.bar(index + bar_width, tuple(data_series[1][1]), bar_width,
                     alpha=opacity,
                     color='r',
                     error_kw=error_config,
                     label='{}'.format(data_series[1][0]))
    box = ax.get_position()
    ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])
    plt.xlabel(x_title, fontsize=10)
    plt.ylabel(y_title, fontsize=10)
    plt.title(g_title, fontsize=11)
    plt.xticks(index + bar_width, tuple(x_labels), fontsize=8)
    plt.yticks(fontsize=8)
    plt.axis('tight')
    lgd = plt.legend(fontsize=8, bbox_to_anchor=(1.15, 0.5))
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('{}/{}.png'.format(images, file_name),
                dpi=100, format='png', bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,),
                bbox_inches='tight')
    return
```

produces this: 
[image: okay]

But I need things to look like this:

[image: better]

How can I adjust my code so everything sits side by side?

Thanks

Comment: what's the issue here? That the legend is lost off the right-hand side?

Comment: Yes.  I'd like both to be on the same horizontal plane like chart 2.  I've tried adjusting with ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width, box.height]) which  I can't get right and bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,), bbox_inches='tight' params, that break my size requirement

Comment: ok, `subplots_adjust` might work. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To control the position of the subplot to make room for the legend, you can use `fig.subplots_adjust`:

```
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.8) # adjust 0.8 for your needs.
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed it.  Thank you for your help.